# storing several strings from a recursive function into a struct c

Tags: c, string, recursion, struct, trie

I am making a predictive text interface by which I store a dictionary into a data structure (ive used a trie), the user searches partially for a word and the completed words are displayed with numbers corresponding to each one. I have done the insertion, search functions and have a recursive traversal that prints out all the completed words(with no numbers). however I want to store them into a struct so that i can use them in another function where the user will then be shown the words with corresponding numbers.

heres the main.c code (for testing it does not go into readfile that enters all 25 000 words!):

```
struct TrieNode* root = trieRootConstructor();
struct TrieNode* pntr = NULL;

trieInsert(root, "aback");
trieInsert(root, "abacus");
trieInsert(root, "abalone");
trieInsert(root, "abandon");
trieInsert(root, "abase");
trieInsert(root, "abash");
trieInsert(root, "abate");
trieInsert(root, "abater");

int x = 0;
char* result = "";
char* search = "aba";

result = trieSearch(root, &pntr, search, result, &x);

printf("\n\n");

traverseTwo(pntr, search);
```

pntr is set to the node where the partial word ends, this is where the traversal will search for the rest of the word.

here is my recursive traversal and its caller:

```
void traverseTwo(struct TrieNode* node, char* partialWord)
{
    char arr[50];
    int index = 0;

    int maxWordSize = 100;
    char wordArr[50][maxWordSize];

    index = recursivePrint(node->children, arr, wordArr[50], 0, partialWord, index);

    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < index; i++)
         printf("%d: %s\n", i, wordArr[i]);

    printf("%d: Continue Typing", index);
}

 int recursivePrint(struct TrieNode* node, char* arr, char* wordArr, int level, char* partialWord, int index)
{
     if(node != NULL)
     {
          arr[level] = node->symbol;

         index = recursivePrint(node->children, arr, wordArr, level+1, partialWord, index);

         if(node->symbol == '\0')
             index = completeWordAndStore(partialWord, arr, wordArr, index);

        index = recursivePrint(node->sibling, arr, wordArr, level, partialWord, index);
    }
    return index;
}

int completeWordAndStore(char* partialWord, char* restOfWord, char* wordArr, int index)
{
    int length = strlen(partialWord) + strlen(restOfWord);
    char completeWord[length];

    strcpy(completeWord, partialWord);
    strcat(completeWord, restOfWord);

    strcpy(wordArr[index], completeWord);

    index++;

    return index;
}
```

I am getting a segmentation fault on `strcpy(wordArr[index], completeWord);`

The idea (in my head) is that once it goes into the if statement where the nodes symbol is '\0' that is where it will store the string at the value of index.

partial word is the part word that has been searched ee.g "aba", i would strcat it with the arr and store it into the struct.

the result should produce:

0: aback
1: abacus
2: abalone
3: abandon
4: abase
5: abash
6: abate
7: abater
8: Continue typing

I do call a destructor later on but that definitely words as its tried and tested.

can anyone suggest how to modify this so that I can store the strings??

I also assume that it would be an array structure if i am correct??

many Thanks

Jack

Comment: It can be anything from a linked list to a hash table, etc... depending on your use cases. Since you say you have done the insertion part, that would ideally be where you would be inserting the words to your container data structure.

Comment: @SelçukCihan i can only use 1 data structure. im using a trie, the insertion is used to put symbols into the trie at nodes. after searching a paritaal word i need to store the rest of the word from the traversal and use it in another function to display it to the user so they can pick their choice of word...

Comment: Oh i see, you would like to store the complete words that begin with the given search key in another place. Since you will be letting the user choose, that should not be a very long list, hence you can use a fixed size array of strings (that is array of char *). To try it quickly just add two more parameters to recursive print: the first one is the array itself that will be storing the strings, second parameter is an index into that array. The second parameter will be modified by the recursive calls, so make it a pointer to an int and increment its value after each insertion.

Comment: @SelçukCihan thanks very much, surely I would only want to increase the second parameter when a '\0' node is reached??? when you say array of char* you mean char* arr[]?? sorry for the questions programming does not come naturally to me so i sometimes struggle to understand

Comment: @SelçukCihan I have done as you said but i had to not use a int* otherwise I got warning and i keep getting a seg fault at the `strcpy(wordArr[index], completeWord);` line

Comment: @SelçukCihan any thoughts??

Comment: Ok using an int and returning it should also work. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide additional details regarding your exact problem.

Comment: @SelçukCihan i have provided more code but i would have to provide basically all the code for the program plus the file that i read into the program... do you want me to do this??

Comment: @Jack Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @rootkea i have now added most of my code and used trieInsert rather than read file just for testing purposes.

Comment: @Jack Which word of *"…Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem"* you didn't understand from the page http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @rootkea which code is not necessary?? i am trying my best, the code i though i gave originally was sufficient...

Comment: @rootkea i have now removed what i believe is unecessary code as, both the trieinsert and search function work how they should

Comment: @Jack Join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100157/chat-with-jack-mvce

Comment: @rootkea i do not have enough rep to chat

Comment: @Jack Missed that. The code you have provided even that's too much code. Reduce it further. Divide code in various modules and comment out each section/module till the problem doesn't disappear. Use `printf` to check intermediate results. Max 10-15 lines of code producing the problem will be ideal

Comment: @rootkea the problem is when i call `strcpy(wordArr[index], completeWord)` it gets a seg fault, if i dont use wordArr and just `printf` the complete word it works, but i want to store them as the user has to be able to choose one via the corresponding number next to it,  then itll display something like you have selected `word[i]` where i is the index of where that word is stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* wordArr[50];
```

You're not allocating any memory for your words. Try with:

```
int maxWordSize = 100;
char wordArr[50][maxWordSize];
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I have updated the code above, it now does print 0 to 8 but rather than words it either prints blank or random symbols... is the implementation ive done right??

Comment: @Jack it's `wordArr[50][maxWordSize]` instead of `wordArr[maxWordSize][50]`

Comment: thanks im afraid its still not printing correctly... have i passed into the functions correctly??

Comment: `strcpy(&(wordArr[index]), completeWord);` => no `&`, `wordArr[index]` is the correct target.

Comment: okay, i now get a warning that i am making a pointer from an integer in 1st argument of strcpy and i get a segmentation error when i run at `strcpy(wordArr[index], completeWord);`

Comment: Uh ? With `strcpy(wordArr[index], completeWord);` you get a warning at that line ?

Comment: yes saying making pointer from integer... specifically argument 1, have i passed them into the functions correctly??

Comment: "have i passed them into the functions correctly" => no. Go to chat ?

Comment: @Jack yes I have an account

Comment: I'll open a chat, I think you can join, wait a sec

Comment: strcpying into wordArr[index] gives you segfault because it is not an address. strcpy treats the first argument as the destination address to which the string will be copied. You should do something like this: strcpy(wordArr + index, completeWord);